# How to calculate with right probabilities values?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

My code solves the equation `G(Ht)` using random `p` probabilities for each value of `d` in my `dlist`. The problem is that the result changes each time because probabilities `p` used are random. So I would like my code use probabilities `p` that would be solutions instead of the random probabilities.In that way, i will be sure to have right result for all `G(Ht)`. Can anyone help please?  Please ask for any details if you need.

```
c = 0.058;
rc = -0.06;
th = 0.80;
dmin = 1;
dmax = 3;
pas = 0.01;
dlist = Range[dmin, dmax, pas];
g1[ε_] := 2*(ε + 0.5)*(ε + 0.5);

f[d_] = Min[{-0.02 + 0.0231397 d, 0.1}];

rt[d_, p_] := ((1 + rc) (1 - p th))/(1 - p) - 1
Ht[d_, p_] := (rt[d, p] - c) d - f[d]
pvalues = RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length[dlist]];
Htlist = MapThread[Ht[#1, #2] &, {dlist, pvalues}];
GHtlist = Map[g1[#] &, Htlist];
formatted = MapThread[{"ème d fixé = ", #1, "G(Ht) = ", #2} &, {dlist, GHtlist}];
formatted = MapIndexed[Prepend[#1, First[#2]] &, formatted];
Grid[formatted]
```

Here below a possible solution:

```
c = 0.058;
 rc = -0.06;
 th = 0.80; 
  g1[ε_] = 2*(ε + 0.5)*(ε + 0.5);
  dmin = 1;
 dmax = 3;
 pas = 0.01; 
dlist = Table[d, {d, dmin, dmax, pas}]
 f[d_] = Min[{-0.02 + 0.0231397 d, 0.038524}]; 
 rt = Simplify[((1 + rc) (1 - p th ))/(1 - p) - 1] 
 Ht = (rt - c) d - f[d]  k[d_, p_] = g1[Ht] - p 
 For[i = 1, i < Length[dlist] + 1,   i++, {Print[i "ème d fixé = ", dlist[[i]]],    Print[NSolve[k[dlist[[i]], p] == 0, p, Reals]]}]
```

Comment: "So I would like my code use probabilities p that would be solutions instead of the random probabilities." - can you explain this further? From where exactly should the p values come from instead?

Comment: @MarcoB,I thought p could come from reals numbers. Please here below an idea :`c = 0.058;
rc = -0.06;
th = 0.80;


g1[ε_] = 2*(ε + 0.5)*(ε + 0.5);

dmin = 1;
dmax = 3;
pas = 0.01;
dlist = Table[d, {d, dmin, dmax, pas}]
Length[dlist]

f[d_] = Min[{-0.02 + 0.0231397 d, 0.038524}];

rt = Simplify[((1 + rc) (1 - p th ))/(1 - p) - 1]

Ht = (rt - c) d - f[d]

k[d_, p_] = g1[Ht] - p

For[i = 1, i < Length[dlist] + 1, 
 i++, {Print[i "ème d fixé = ", dlist[[i]]], 
  Print[NSolve[k[dlist[[i]], p] == 0, p, Reals]]}]`.

Comment: @MarcoB, I can have de `p`solution but i don't know how to mix this code for solving my `G(Ht)`  equation in my first message.

Comment: That code you showed me is mostly the same as the one you have in the qeustion. Edit the question to add it in as a possible solution so it is more readable, but please leave out the definitions that are identical. I am still not sure that I understand where p should come from though.

Comment: Yes i will add it as a possible solution. btw, as you can see in the second code, there is no  place where i whrote the  `G(Ht)` equation. This  equation is what iam trying and would like to solve by using probabilities  `p` as real numbers:  `Print[NSolve[k[dlist[[i]], p] == 0, p, Reals]]}]`.